# Constructor in toplink model class

Tags: toplink

Can I have a non default multiple argument constructor in toplink. For example

```
public class Employee {
   private String empId;
   public Employee(String empId) {
      this.empId = empId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, however a default constructor must still be available for toplink as well. Toplink uses the default constructor and setters/properties to initialize your object.